# How to implement Blowfish CBC algorithm space Padding

Tags: java, encryption, padding, space

I have to implement java cipher space padding. I am trying to write like to like implementation of Perl code where Blowfish/CBC/space mode is supported. I couldn't find relevant mode in Java Cipher list and only supports PCK5Padding and NoPadding. Is Java supports space padding if so could anyone assist me.

Answer (score 1):

`Space` padding is adding spaces so the length is a multiple of 8 when encrypting, or trimming spaces after decrypting. In Java, you can use `NoPadding` and manage the spacing yourself.

For example, to encrypt in Perl, and decrypt in Java:

**Perl:**

```
use Crypt::CBC;

$cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -literal_key => 1,
    -key => pack("H*",
      "11223344556677889900112233445566778899001122334"
      . "455667788990011223344556677889900112233445566"
      . "77889900112233445566"),
    -cipher => 'Blowfish',
    -header => 'none',
    -padding => 'space',
    -iv => pack("H*", '1234567812345678')
);

$ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt_hex("Message");
print(join('',unpack('H*',$cipher->iv())));
print $ciphertext;
```

**Output:** `1234567812345678e70b9ab0a4262ba8`

**Java:**

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.codec.Charsets;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish/CBC/NoPadding");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(Hex.decodeHex(
            "11223344556677889900112233445566778899001122334"
              + "455667788990011223344556677889900112233445566"
              + "77889900112233445566"),
            "Blowfish");
        byte[] iv = Hex.decodeHex("1234567812345678");

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex("e70b9ab0a4262ba8"));

        System.out.println(new String(result, Charsets.UTF_8).trim());
    }
}
```

**Output:** `Message`